# Private method Unit testing with Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I was coding test cases for an angular application using jasmine. But many internal methods are declared as private in the services.

Example:

```
App.service('productDisplay', function(){
    var myPrivate = function(){
        //do sth
    }
    this.doOfferCal = function(product, date){
        //call myPrivate
        //do sth too
        return offer;
    }
});
```

Using jasmine it straightforward to code test for "doOfferCal" but I want to write unit test for myPrivate too.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is possible, try to avoid accessing private methods in the unit tests. Try initializing everything it's necessary and then just call the public method and expect the result. The test shouldn't be aware of all the implementations inside of your service. If in the future you will change the private method or replace it with something else but get the same result, the test will break because it knows about your private method. On the other hand, if you call just the public method and check just the result, you can change any time the logic inside, the test will remain stable.

Answer (score 21):

Thanks jabko87.

In addition, if you want to pass the the arguments use the below example:

```
const myPrivateSpy = spyOn<any>(service, 'transformNative').and.callThrough();
 myPrivateSpy.call(service, {name: 'PR'});
```

Note: Here service is the Class, transformNative is the private method and {name: 'PR'} passing an object argument

Comment: Nice! Makes TDD in TypeScript possible with private methods.

Comment: This is great, but what do you call in the expect(service.nativeMethod). ... statement?

Comment: That service.nativeMethod still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 10):

Is there a specific reason you wish to test your private methods?

By testing `doOfferCal()`, you're implicitly testing that `myPrivate()` is doing the right thing.

Though this is for RailsConf, Sandi Metz has a very good talk on [what should be tested](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M).

Comment: My "doOfferCal" calling many private methods and finally returning a complex result as why thought it would be good to test each private methods. By the way do you have any suggestion in this situation?

Comment: One school of thought is that private methods are implementation details. By testing your private methods, your tests will break even though your public method is still acting correctly. As a result, you may end up creating tests that are too brittle and scare off developers from improving/refactoring the implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize pressing enter will submit my post.. What I would do in this case is test `doOfferCal()` and then verify the complex object it returns. If that test passes, all the private methods in between are working as intended. I'm sure you'll find people in support of private methods, but this is what I've found works best for me in terms of writing useful and maintainable unit tests.

Comment: Also, this will give you the freedom of optimizing the implementation of `doOfferCal()` without breaking any unit tests.

Comment: I got your point, but my client doesn't. He insists, that we have 100% on code coverage tool at any circumstances.

Comment: @TomaszSzymanek You should still be able to have 100% code coverage by testing the public method that interacts with your private method.

Answer (score 10):

Achan is 100% right, but if you really need to call private method in your tests (what should be never :-) ) you can do it by:

```
var myPrivateSpy = spyOn(productDisplayService, "myPrivate").and.callThrough();
myPrivateSpy.call();
```

Comment: Why should you never call private methods in your tests?  I'm new to testing, how do you test private methods if you don't call them?

Comment: @Micah `private` methods are used by `public` ones so it is sufficient to test only those. Private methods are implementation detail and as long `public` method works as supposed it is ok. By testing `private` method you also break encapsulation and create tests duplication (there will be an intersection of test cases for `public` and `private` methods).

Comment: Thank you @Michal

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call your private method you just have to do it like this:

```
component["thePrivateMethodName"](parameters);
```

Where `component` is your service class or component class.

Comment: I wrote it just to show how to call a private method, but I don't recommend it. This implementation can be fragile on changes, if the method is renamed, you would not get an error just the tests will fail and you have to find out why.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I would be bold enough to demonstrate a valid use case for testing private methods: I have a story which involved consolidating a couple of features.  The previous engineer had made public a number of methods that could have been private.  They all had tests.

To keep the tests running while I did the consolidation and figure out how to test the calling method appropriately, I wanted to continue to test those private methods.

This answer was perfect; straightforward, saved me a ton of commenting, and gave me the red-green-refactor pattern that I needed.

Answer (score 2):

To test inner functions I call the outer function that calls the inner function and then vary my input according to what the inner function requires. So, in your case you would call `productDisplay` and vary your input based upon what `myPrivate` needs and then verify that you have the expected output. You could also spy on `myPrivate` and test things that way using `.havebeencalledwith` or `.andcallthrough`.