# Angular testing: testing angular Services with private methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-services

lets say I got this kind of method on a service:

```
this.search = function (term) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

             Restangular.all('search').getList(params)
                .then(_onRestResult.bind(this, deferred))
                .catch(_onRestError.bind(this, deferred));


            return deferred.promise;
        }

function _onRestResult(deferred, data) { // notice it isn't on the this

//doSomthing
}
```

But running a basic test.

when I change the `then` clause to an anonymous function, everything works as expected, but when I used the named private function I get:
karma prints:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   '_onRestResult.bind(this,deferred)')

I'm aware of this kind of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966989/how-to-write-testable-controllers-with-private-methods-in-angularjs)

but they refer to controllers and not services (:)) and suggest not using private methods, but we really prefer using them.

I also run into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885635/private-method-unit-testing-with-jasmine) that suggests the private methods are implicitly tested, which was what I thought, until I run into this error messages.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** I should notice I'm mocking Restangular like this (if this is relevant):

```
mockRestangular = {

                one:function(){
                    return this;
                },

                getList:function(calls){
                       answer ={results:['1','2']}

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(answer);
                    return deferred.promise;
                },

                post:function(called){
                    answer = 'posted: '+called;
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(answer);
                    return deferred.promise;

                },
                get: function(called){
                    answer = this;
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(answer);
                    return deferred.promise;
                },


                all:function(){
                    return this;
                }

            };
```

Comment: Can you create a plunkr with example code?

Comment: Can you add example `then` with anonymous function that works for you?

Comment: I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6aUDu/3/ I think this is what you describe, but it seems to work for me. Can you provide an fiddle that breaks?

Comment: @hassassin, thanks for the effort! I think you are missing something with my question since the fiddle isn't running in an angular unittest (karma/jasmine or otherwise). As I stated in the question - using private methods works in the service It self. the problem was with testing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: This turned to be a completely different problem. Vague karma/chai error messages led me in the wrong direction. The actual problem (if someone bumps into this issue again, which I believe they will..) is the `bind` method. Turned out the ````` phantomjs```` The headless browser we are running the tests with, Doesn't support `````bind``` (as some other es5 methods, not all). Running the same tests with chrome/firefox works perfectly. Once I understood this was the problem, then solving was easy, just added an ES5-shim lib (that included bind) to the karma.conf.js configuration as an included file (or the way you add helpers in any other framework) and everything works perfectlly