# Sinon.stub works in karma, mocha with chrome running but not headless

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, stub, sinon

I am working on an angularjs project where if a user scrolls on an element, the element calls scrollTop() to determine if another method should be called.

I wrote this sinon.stub

scrollTopStub = sinon.stub($.fn, "scrollTop").returns(50);

This is the validation

expect($.fn.scrollTop.calledOnce).to.be.true;

The tests pass when I run them using karma, mocha and chrome.

However, when I run the tests headless the sinon stub is never called.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I was never able to get this stub to work. I finally had to make the function part of the link scope and this overwrite the scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. But if someone bumps into this: this is probably  a completely different issue. I run into a [similiar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230101/angular-testing-testing-angular-services-with-private-methods) once almost been driven crazy by cryptic and misleading errors when running with phantomjs (I assume this is the headless browser) - in the end I found out that **Phantomjs doesn't support bind (and some other es5 methods** So code using them would fail. just adding es5 shim to the test index.html (or karma.conf or.. ) file solved the problem.  Since I used sinon.js with phantomjs in another project I know this can work correctly

Comment: Really old question (and answer), but still relevant. In my case, I had to prepend `'node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js'` to Karma's `files`, so we can use all polyfills provided by Babel when running the tests with PhantomJS.